# SharedPreferences Across Activities returning null inside Child Fragment

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Hey Guys i am trying to save some information SharedPreferences inside my Main activities. But when i am accessing the same info inside other activity's child fragment it is returning null.

This is what i am doing 
Main Activity

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplication().getSharedPreferences("UserDataInitially", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();   
 editor.putString("UserSearch",skill_set);
 editor.apply();
 editor.commit();
```

Now when I access SharedPreferences in another activity's OnCreate method they are returning values

MainActivityUser

```
    String skill_set;
    SharedPreferences UserDataInitially = getApplication().getSharedPreferences("UserDataInitially", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    skill_set = UserDataInitially.getString("UserSearch","");
```

but inside the child fragment of MainActivityUser

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);

        SharedPreferences UserDataInitially= getContext().getSharedPreferences("UserDataInitially", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      skill_set = UserDataInitially.getString("UserSearch","");
      // Here skill_set is null
    }
}
```

Comment: try to use without editor.apply();

Comment: Not working but i found a strange thing they are working fine in another activity without any change but no where else.

Comment: then try to use  SharedPreferences UserDataInitially= getActivity().getApplication().getSharedPreferences("UserDataInitially", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: not working with getActivity().getApplication() also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work, it is because you are using different context

```
 private void saveString(String key, String value) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.apply();
}

private String getString(String key, String defaultValue) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    return sharedPreferences.getString(key, defaultValue);
}
```

refer to [getDefaultSharedPreferences()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#getDefaultSharedPreferences(android.content.Context))

Comment: its still not working but i found something i tried a toast inside the oncreate() method of fragment and the toast is not displayed somehow oncreate() is not called of the fragment

Comment: they are working fine insde the oncreateView() method thanks for the help